# Advice on using flyway for non-db migrations?

Tags: liquibase, flyway

I'm currently evaluating both Flyway and Liquibase for use in our large, existing project. Either seems like they would fit the bill well for sql migrations, but unfortunately we also have the requirement to occasionally do filesystem migrations (like applying an xsl transform).

I don't see any reason why Flyway can't technically do this under the guise of a java migration, but I wonder if trying to do this is a case of fitting a round peg in a square hole - mayhap there is another tool to track filesystem-related stuff? I sure do like the idea of using just one migration tool for everything though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It should work as there is no technical limitation stopping you from doing this.

(Even though this is a use case I never thought about when designing it)